# Динамическое добавление алиасов на сайте

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, сервер, alias

У меня есть сервис **service.ru**. Сервис позволяет, к примеру, создавать лендинг, который после создания доступен по адресу **app.service.ru/34cea4529dee99485faa2342983bb2cf**.

Нашему пользователю необходимо, чтобы созданная страница открывалась не по этому длинному нашему адресу, а по его фирменному, например, **landing.client.ru**. Клиентов может быть сколь угодно много: **landing.client1.ru**, **landing.client2.ru**, **landing.client3.ru** и так далее, поэтому решение должно быть масштабируемым.
Важно, что после перехода на **landing.client.ru** *не должен происходить редирект* на **app.service.ru/34cea4529dee99485faa2342983bb2cf**, а в адресной строке браузера должен остаться **landing.client.ru**, но открыться должна страница **app.service.ru/34cea4529dee99485faa2342983bb2cf**
Этот эффект виден при открытии яндекс.рф (открывается обычный yandex.ru, но в адресной строке сохраняется яндекс.рф).

Насколько мне удалось узнать, это делается как-то через алиасы, а не редиректы. Вариант со встраиванием клиенту на страницу landing.client.ru iframe с нашим лендингом не рассматривается. Я уверен, что задачу можно как-то решить с редактированием DNS у клиента и с определенными настройками на стороне service.ru/app.service.ru.

Я изучил много разных источников, но один хочу отметить здесь — https://stackoverflow.com/a/17753713 — я прописал у **landing.client.ru CNAME cname.service.ru** (теперь обращение идет к ip нашего сервера при переходе по **landing.client.ru**. Также я понял, что мне нужен VPS, а не обычный хостинг).
Я понимаю, что редактирование CNAME не осуществляет открытие другого сайта, а просто дает ip для обращения.

Из разных статей в интернете я понял, что когда открывается **landing.client.ru**, то идет обращение к ip, на котором лежит **cname.service.ru**, однако, далее целевой сервер должен понять, что от него хотят (а именно нужно открыть, к примеру,  **app.service.ru/34cea4529dee99485faa2342983bb2cf**).

Я видел, что вроде алиасы прописывают в конфиге Apache, но даже если так, то не понимаю, как добавление этих алиасов можно сделать динамическим.

Так как я в этой теме сильно плаваю, описание вопроса получилось сумбурным, но я надеюсь, что этой информации достаточно, чтобы понять, что я пытаюсь сделать.

Спасибо.